# Is the Euclidean Pythagorean Theorem true for right triangles in Poincare's half plane?

Tags: geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

Suppose we have a right triangle ABC in the Poincare half plane such that angle C = $\frac \pi2$. Is it possible to construct this triangle with the property that $d(A, B)^2 + d(A, C)^2 = d(B, C)^2$ where $d(P_1, P_2)$ is the hyperbolic distance from point $P_1$ to $P_2$?

I'm leaning towards no (purely intuition), but I can't quite figure out exactly why.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: The hyperbolic counterpart of the Pythagorean Theorem is $\cosh a \cosh b = \cosh c$. See, more generally, the [Law of Cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_law_of_cosines). In hyperbolic geometry, "raw" segment lengths very-rarely appear in formulas; they're almost-always wrapped in hyperbolic trig functions.

Comment: Yes, that's something that I know already. To clarify exactly what I'm asking, I know that in Euclidean geometry a right triangle the typical property $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ is true. From your comment @Blue I'm inferring that this formula does NOT hold for hyperbolic geometry? And if that's the case, how can I prove this? Perhaps with geodesic manipulation?

Comment: If the formula $\cosh a \cosh b = \cosh c$ holds, then the formula $a^2+b^2=c^2$ cannot hold. (*Infinitesimally*, however, the relations agree: Since $\cosh x = 1 - x^2/2! + x^4/4!-\cdots$, we have $(1-a^2/2+\cdots)(1-b^2/2+\cdots)=(1-c^2/2+\cdots)$. At infinitesimal scale, we can ignore higher-order terms —that is, we can drop the "$\cdots$" and also $a^2b^2$— and the relation reduces to $a^2+b^2=c^2$.) You can prove the relation using the Poincare disk model and distance formula $d(p,q) = 2\operatorname{arctanh}D(p,q)$, where $d$ and $D$ are hyperbolic and Euclidean distances, respectively.

Comment: See, for instance, [Wilson Stothers' geometry pages](https://www.maths.gla.ac.uk/wws/cabripages/hyperbolic/hypertrig.html). (The pages lack nice mathematical formatting, but they're informative.)

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Blue wrote in a comment, the [counterpart to the Pythagorean theorem in hyperbolic geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem#Hyperbolic_geometry) (with [Gaussian curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_curvature) $-1$) is

$$\cosh a\cdot\cosh b=\cosh c$$

The [Taylor series of $\cosh$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function#Taylor_series_expressions) is $\cosh x = 1+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+\cdots$. For small lengths you may ignore all terms of degree $4$ and above, and you end up with something that converges to the regular Euclidean law. Using [big-Oh notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Infinitesimal_asymptotics) for the error terms you'd get

$$\cosh a\cdot\cosh b=\left(1+\frac{a^2}2+O(a^4)\right)\left(1+\frac{b^2}2+O(b^4)\right)=\\
1+\frac{a^2}2+\frac{b^2}2+O(a^4)+O(a^2b^2)+O(b^4)=1+\frac{c^2}2+O(c^4)=\cosh c$$

I find this consideration useful in understanding how the product in hyperbolic geometry can correspond to the sum in Euclidean geometry.